# why the navigationdrawer is not appearing

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

in the below posted code i am tryin to have `navigationdrawer`, i followed the steps in a tutorial but when i run the App the `navigationdrawer` does not show up.

please let me know why it does not show-up

**mainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private String[] navDrawerOptions;
private TypedArray navDrawerIcons;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerModell> navDrawerModel;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

private final String ECO_ASSISTANT_DESC = "Eco-Assistant menu item is to ......";
private final String DATA_LOGGER_DESC = "Data-Logger menu item item is to ......";
private final String EXIT_DESC = "Press here to exit";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initViews(R.layout.main_activity);
}

private void initViews(int main_activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(main_activity);
    navDrawerOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    navDrawerIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerListView);

    navDrawerModel = new ArrayList<NavDrawerModell>();

    navDrawerModel.add(new NavDrawerModell(navDrawerIcons.getResourceId(0, -1), navDrawerOptions[0], ECO_ASSISTANT_DESC));
    navDrawerModel.add(new NavDrawerModell(navDrawerIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), navDrawerOptions[1], DATA_LOGGER_DESC));
    navDrawerModel.add(new NavDrawerModell(navDrawerIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), navDrawerOptions[2], ECO_ASSISTANT_DESC));
    navDrawerIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this.navDrawerModel);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

}

**Adapter**:

```
    public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerModell> navDrawerModel;

public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerModell> navDrawerModell) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerModel = navDrawerModell;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.navDrawerModel.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.navDrawerModel.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_layout, null);
    }

    ImageView iv_Icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_navDrawerOptionImage);
    TextView tv_Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_navDrawerOptionTitle);
    TextView tv_Desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_navDrawerOptionDescription);

    iv_Icon.setImageResource(navDrawerModel.get(position).getIcon());
    tv_Title.setText(navDrawerModel.get(position).gettitle());
    tv_Desc.setText(navDrawerModel.get(position).getDescription());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

**Modell**:
    public class NavDrawerModell {

```
private int icon;
private String title;
private String description;

public NavDrawerModell(int icon, String title, String description) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.icon = icon;
    this.title = title;
    this.description  = description;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
public int getIcon() {
    return this.icon;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String gettitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public void setDescription(String desc) {
    this.description = desc;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented the [Listen for Open and Close Events](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#OpenClose) part? You need to add `ActionBarDrawerToggle` to handle Open and Close events.

Comment: Use the one from support-v7-appcompat. And also if you want to synchronize the drawer with Home button clicks, you need to implement the [Open and Close with the App Icon](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon) part as well, just like Boban S. have suggested.

Comment: currently i have "import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;" and i changed it to be "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;" bu it is not defined

Comment: Did you import it the support-v7-appcompat library?

Comment: yes, and i am using "navDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_home, R.string.navDrawer_opened, 
          R.string.navDrawer_closed);
 }" but eclipse says it is undefined as a constructor

Comment: and the constructor signature is exactly as what is posted in andridDev website https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: Not really. [Old constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int,%20int)) has the drawerImageRes parameter, and [the new one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20int,%20int)) does not. Simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial to create navigation drawer https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Create drawer toggle and override `onPostCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged` methods.